# Crash log EXC CRASH SIGABRT - iOS 10.3.2

Tags: ios, facebook, sigabrt, react-native-ios

Can anyone assist me on how to interpret this crash log? The app crashes when a user attempts to login using Facebook. I cannot duplicate this error and I`m new to debugging. Thanks

Date/Time:           2017-06-03 07:02:28.5051 -0700
Launch Time:         2017-06-03 07:02:23.7070 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F89)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  2

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18ee12fe0 0x18d874538 0x18ee12f28 0x10014f6c8 0x100149c04 0x18ee18e80 0x18ed0e2c4 0x18ed12e9c 0x10014d624 0x1001734c4 0x100172e74 0x18dcca9e0 0x18dcca9a0 0x18dcd8ad4 0x18dcce2cc 0x18dcd8fa8 0x18dcdaa50 0x18dcda7d0 0x18ded3100 0x18ded2cac)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ddef224 0x18ddee000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ddef09c 0x18ddee000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018edc0e90 0x18ece6000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018edbeae4 0x18ece6000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018eceeda4 0x18ece6000 + 36260
5   GraphicsServices                0x0000000190758074 0x19074c000 + 49268
6   UIKit                           0x0000000194fa2058 0x194f2d000 + 479320
7   InvestmentApp                       0x00000001000638c4 0x10005c000 + 30916
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018dcfd59c 0x18dcf9000 + 17820

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de0da88 0x18ddee000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded31a4 0x18ded2000 + 4516
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded2cac 0x18ded2000 + 3244

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de0d014 0x18ddee000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded7264 0x18ded2000 + 21092
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018dd819c4 0x18dd20000 + 399812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018d84d1b0 0x18d84c000 + 4528
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018d866c04 0x18d84c000 + 109572
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018d874820 0x18d86c000 + 34848
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018d8635d4 0x18d84c000 + 95700
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018d862ef8 0x18d84c000 + 93944
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018d87466c 0x18d86c000 + 34412
9   InvestmentApp                       0x000000010017363c 0x10005c000 + 1144380
10  InvestmentApp                       0x0000000100172e74 0x10005c000 + 1142388
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcca9e0 0x18dcc9000 + 6624
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcca9a0 0x18dcc9000 + 6560
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcd8ad4 0x18dcc9000 + 64212
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcce2cc 0x18dcc9000 + 21196
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcd8fa8 0x18dcc9000 + 65448
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcdaa50 0x18dcc9000 + 72272
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcda7d0 0x18dcc9000 + 71632
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded3100 0x18ded2000 + 4352
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded2cac 0x18ded2000 + 3244

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded2ca8 0x18ded2000 + 3240

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ddef224 0x18ddee000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ddef09c 0x18ddee000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018edc0e90 0x18ece6000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018edbeae4 0x18ece6000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018eceeda4 0x18ece6000 + 36260
5   Foundation                      0x000000018f808d74 0x18f7fc000 + 52596
6   Foundation                      0x000000018f829b44 0x18f7fc000 + 187204
7   UIKit                           0x000000019592c6a8 0x194f2d000 + 10483368
8   Foundation                      0x000000018f9062d8 0x18f7fc000 + 1090264
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded568c 0x18ded2000 + 13964
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded559c 0x18ded2000 + 13724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded2cb4 0x18ded2000 + 3252

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de0da88 0x18ddee000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded2fd0 0x18ded2000 + 4048
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded2cac 0x18ded2000 + 3244

Thread 6 name:  com.facebook.react.JavaScript
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ddef224 0x18ddee000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ddef09c 0x18ddee000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018edc0e90 0x18ece6000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018edbeae4 0x18ece6000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018eceeda4 0x18ece6000 + 36260
5   InvestmentApp                       0x0000000100169760 0x10005c000 + 1103712
6   Foundation                      0x000000018f9062d8 0x18f7fc000 + 1090264
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded568c 0x18ded2000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded559c 0x18ded2000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded2cb4 0x18ded2000 + 3252

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de0d314 0x18ddee000 + 127764
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018dd2c8b0 0x18dd20000 + 51376
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018d83d3c4 0x18d7f6000 + 291780
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019369adb8 0x192ce1000 + 10198456
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193699df8 0x192ce1000 + 10194424
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193699c34 0x192ce1000 + 10193972
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000193699adc 0x192ce1000 + 10193628
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019369aebc 0x192ce1000 + 10198716
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019369ade8 0x192ce1000 + 10198504
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019369b098 0x192ce1000 + 10199192
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded568c 0x18ded2000 + 13964
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded559c 0x18ded2000 + 13724
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded2cb4 0x18ded2000 + 3252

Thread 8 name:  WebThread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de0da88 0x18ddee000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded7b60 0x18ded2000 + 23392
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcdbcec 0x18dcc9000 + 77036
3   QuartzCore                      0x000000019201a5f4 0x192013000 + 30196
4   QuartzCore                      0x00000001921a5f4c 0x192013000 + 1650508
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000192029550 0x192013000 + 91472
6   QuartzCore                      0x0000000192129a08 0x192013000 + 1141256
7   QuartzCore                      0x00000001921296c8 0x192013000 + 1140424
8   QuartzCore                      0x000000019211ec20 0x192013000 + 1096736
9   QuartzCore                      0x000000019211ecb4 0x192013000 + 1096884
10  QuartzCore                      0x000000019209a34c 0x192013000 + 553804
11  QuartzCore                      0x00000001920c13ac 0x192013000 + 713644
12  QuartzCore                      0x00000001920c1e78 0x192013000 + 716408
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018edc09a8 0x18ece6000 + 895400
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018edbe630 0x18ece6000 + 886320
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018eceedc4 0x18ece6000 + 36292
16  WebCore                         0x00000001939b9608 0x193976000 + 275976
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded568c 0x18ded2000 + 13964
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded559c 0x18ded2000 + 13724
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded2cb4 0x18ded2000 + 3252

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ddef224 0x18ddee000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ddef09c 0x18ddee000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018edc0e90 0x18ece6000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018edbeae4 0x18ece6000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018eceeda4 0x18ece6000 + 36260
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018f4fadf4 0x18f419000 + 925172
6   Foundation                      0x000000018f9062d8 0x18f7fc000 + 1090264
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded568c 0x18ded2000 + 13964
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded559c 0x18ded2000 + 13724
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded2cb4 0x18ded2000 + 3252

Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: CA::CG::RenderQueue
Thread 10:
0   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000190279574 0x190207000 + 468340
1   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000190279564 0x190207000 + 468324
2   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001903e3ef4 0x190207000 + 1953524
3   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001903eb860 0x190207000 + 1984608
4   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001903eb0b8 0x190207000 + 1982648
5   CoreGraphics                    0x000000019020b1c0 0x190207000 + 16832
6   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001903ff9a4 0x190207000 + 2066852
7   CoreGraphics                    0x00000001903efb50 0x190207000 + 2001744
8   QuartzCore                      0x0000000192169ff0 0x192013000 + 1404912
9   QuartzCore                      0x000000019217ebc8 0x192013000 + 1489864
10  QuartzCore                      0x00000001921a3a1c 0x192013000 + 1640988
11  QuartzCore                      0x00000001921a43c4 0x192013000 + 1643460
12  QuartzCore                      0x000000019216a544 0x192013000 + 1406276
13  QuartzCore                      0x000000019201a314 0x192013000 + 29460
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcca9a0 0x18dcc9000 + 6560
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcdbc80 0x18dcc9000 + 76928
16  QuartzCore                      0x00000001920199e0 0x192013000 + 27104
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcca9a0 0x18dcc9000 + 6560
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcd8830 0x18dcc9000 + 63536
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcce2cc 0x18dcc9000 + 21196
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcdaa50 0x18dcc9000 + 72272
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018dcda7d0 0x18dcc9000 + 71632
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded3100 0x18ded2000 + 4352
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ded2cac 0x18ded2000 + 3244

Thread 2 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001742e5337
    x4: 0x000000018d867b07   x5: 0x000000016df895e0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x000000000c000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000b  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x0000000000000010  x13: 0x000000018f05dc0e  x14: 0x0000080000000800  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000016df8b000  x21: 0x000000016df895e0  x22: 0x0000000174607950  x23: 0x0000000195a7f320
   x24: 0x000000017411aaf0  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x0000000195a7f000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0xb0000000000001b5   fp: 0x000000016df89540   lr: 0x000000018ded7264
    sp: 0x000000016df89520   pc: 0x000000018de0d014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: First you need re-symbolicate your crash in order to try to find what is wrong

Comment: Hi @ReinierMelian, Here is the log: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/94f6a6b0a6c357076db04018c4f2c14520170607133952/010f8116effe6b3e0e5492bf4261f41920170607133952/94176a